# Validate whether a column contains phone number in correct format using R

Tags: regex, r, pattern-matching

I have a column in a data frame(df) containing phone numbers. I need to check whether the phone numbers adhere to below format:

X XXX XXX-XXXX

I want the output as:

```
         phone              
1 234 564-8988    TRUE                                 
22 32545-35647   FALSE                           
1-222-225-0202   FALSE
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Take a look at any number of commercial websites which allow you to enter eleven digits as a string, or with arbitrary non-numeric delimiters (12345678901, 1-234-567-8901, 1.234.567.8901, etc) and then run a regex or other parser to remove the unwanted characters.  Don't make the user do the work that some simple software can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grepl` in R.  Here I call the new column `TF`

```
> d <- data.frame(phone = c("1 234 564-8988", 
                            "22 32545-35647", "1-222-225-0202"))
> d$TF <- grepl("[0-9] [0-9]{3} [0-9(-)0-9]", d$phone)
> d
#            phone    TF
# 1 1 234 564-8988  TRUE
# 2 22 32545-35647 FALSE
# 3 1-222-225-0202 FALSE
```

More simply, the regular expression may be okay as `"^[0-9] "`, since you only want the phone numbers that begin with one number and then a space.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to match only the phone numbers which are in this  `X XXX XXX-XXXX` format,

```
^[0-9] [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$
```